# What generic view should be used to create friend request in drf?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

I am building a drf backend api for my android app. I need the API to be able to send friend requests to the relevant users from a user. To do this I am using the [django-friendship](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship) library. In their documentation they say:

> Create a friendship request:

```
other_user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
Friend.objects.add_friend(
    request.user,                               # The sender
    other_user,                                 # The recipient
    message='Hi! I would like to add you')      # This message is optional
```

My question is where should this code be written. I know that it belongs in a view, but what kind of view? Could someone give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably add it to the view that handles any update to the users friendships. For example, if you have a view that handles submission of a friend requests via some endpoint it might look like this:

```py
class CreateFriendRequestView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        other_user = User.objects.get(pk=request.data['other_user'])
        Friend.objects.add_friend(
            request.user,                              
            other_user,                                 
        message='Hi! I would like to add you')
        return Response({'status': 'Request sent'}, status=201)
```

Comment: Do i have to return a response?

Comment: @TomFinet That's up to you, I just did because a REST api usually would give acknowledgement that a request was processed properly.

Comment: Is this best practice?

Comment: @TomFinet that also depends on the use case, for example, sending a forgot password email shouldn't give back an informative response since it can be a security risk. In this case though, it would be good practice to send the response since it complies with the REST specification.

Comment: @TomFinet http://restfulapi.net/ has some good points on REST API design

Comment: Could a response code system be used so that the client can interpret the response instead of the response in the form of a string?

Comment: @TomFinet yes, that what the response status can be used for. Look at [HTTP Status Codes](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) Btw, if you think my answer and comments have been helpful, I'd appreciate some upvotes if possible

Comment: Yeah dont worry, you have been really helpful, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150289/discussion-between-mattjegan-and-tom-finet).